# What is the problem with this preprocessor in the code below?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor

```
//C code starts
#define mod(a)  (a>=0?a:-a)
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x,y,z;
    scanf("%d%d%d",&x,&y,&z);
    printf("%d %d %d    %d %d\n",x,y,z,y-z,x-z);
    if(mod(y-x)<mod(x-z))   printf("%d %d Cat A",mod(y-z),mod(x-z));
    else if(mod(y-z)>mod(x-z))  printf("%d %d Cat B",mod(y-z),mod(x-z));
    else printf("Mouse C");
    printf("\n");
}
/*code ends here*/
```

For the input of "1 3 2" I would expect the output to be "Mouse C" but it is not the case.

Also if we add all the variables in mod in one more bracket (e.g. if the `mod(y-z)` is then written as `mod((y-z))` ) then the output comes as expected.
So why it is going on?

Comment: The problem is that you're using the preprocessor for things that should be a function :)

Comment: Think of macro's as a copy-paste. No intelligence whatsoever. the `a` in `mod(a)` is whatever expression you put there. It's not a function, after all, it's a macro. Applied to `mod(y-z)` means you're substituting `a` for `y-z`. Check what your code looks like once the preprocessor has done its job (`gcc -E your_code.c`)

Answer (score 3):

Macros perform direct text (or more accurately, *token*) substitution.  So this:

```
mod(y-x)
```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
(y-x>=0?y-x:-y-x)
```

Notice that the last part is `-y-x`, i.e. the negation of `y` minus `x`, while what you wanted was `-(y-x)`.  This is a prime example of why macro arguments should always be placed in parenthesis as follows:

```
#define mod(a)  ((a)>=0?(a):-(a))
```

When you want to see what your macro *actually* does, look at your code after the preprocessor has actually done its job:

- `gcc -E file.c`
- `clang -E file.c` or `clang --preprocess file.c`
- `cl.exe /E file.c`, `cl.exe /P file.c`, or `cl.exe /EP file.c` for those on windows

Answer (score 1):

It's in general a bad idea to use macros for these things. Use a function instead.

First thing is that you the preprocessor just replaces text. `mod(y-x)` will be expanded to `(y-x>=0?y-x:-y-x)` which is obviously wrong. You can remedy this with

```
#define mod(a) ((a)>=0?(a):-(a))
```

But here's another catch. Suppose you do this:

```
mod(f())
```

where `f` is a function with side effects. For instance the `rand()` function. The macro would then make three function calls.

You can solve this problem in `gcc` (thus making it non-portable) with this construct:

```
#define mod(a) ({ int _a=a; _a>=0?_a:-_a; })
```

But isn't it easier to just do this?

```
long long mod(a) {
    return a>=0?a:-a;
}
```